# Expresion regular busqueda de coma

Tags: regex

estoy tratando de crear una expresión regular que capture cada linea ej

una expresión para que busque la primera coma
otra que busque la segunda coma y asi sucesivamente.

`Santa Elena.- FOJAS 8148 NUMERO 11796 del año 2016, a FOJAS 8148 NUMERO 11797 del año 2016, a FOJAS 8149 NUMERO 11798 del año 2016, a FOJAS 8150 NUMERO 11799 del año 2016, a FOJAS 8151 NUMERO 11800 del año 2016, a FOJAS 8152 NUMERO 11801 del año 2016, y a FOJAS 8153 NUMERO 11802 del año 2016.- Lo expuesto consta en la escritura`

> .*(?=(a))

estaba usando esa expresión

Comment: No entiendo bien con lo que te referis a cada linea ¿Las lineas estan diferenciadas por las comas? `[^,]+(?=,|$)` esta expresion regular divide todo por comas ¿Es esto a lo que te referis?

Comment: aquella expresión me ha servido, pero me quedo en la duda para seguir con la siguiente coma

Comment: ¿A que te referis con seguir con la siguiente coma?

Comment: humm como un contador, ej: con la expresion que me has compartido, busca la primera coincidencia de "," pero algo que busque la segunda ","

Comment: que tome la siguente "linea" ej: a FOJAS 8148 NUMERO 11797 del año 2016,

Comment: A mi me la estaria tomando, tal vez si usas la \g al final para hacerla global

Comment: gracias por la información estimado !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías probar con `[^,]+`

La implementación dependerá del lenguaje de programación que utilices. Por ejemplo en javascript podrías hacerlo así:

```js
var re = /[^,]+/g;
var s = 'Santa Elena.- FOJAS 8148 NUMERO 11796 del año 2016, a FOJAS 8148 NUMERO 11797 del año 2016, a FOJAS 8149 NUMERO 11798 del año 2016, a FOJAS 8150 NUMERO 11799 del año 2016, a FOJAS 8151 NUMERO 11800 del año 2016, a FOJAS 8152 NUMERO 11801 del año 2016, y a FOJAS 8153 NUMERO 11802 del año 2016.- Lo expuesto consta en la escritura';
var m;

while (m = re.exec(s)) {
  alert(m);
}
```

Aun más elegante sería dividir por comas. Prácticamente cualquier lenguaje de programación ofrece un método/función `split` o similar.

Por ejemplo, en js:

```
var s = 'Santa Elena.- FOJAS 8148 NUMERO 11796 del año 2016, a FOJAS 8148 NUMERO 11797 del año 2016, a FOJAS 8149 NUMERO 11798 del año 2016, a FOJAS 8150 NUMERO 11799 del año 2016, a FOJAS 8151 NUMERO 11800 del año 2016, a FOJAS 8152 NUMERO 11801 del año 2016, y a FOJAS 8153 NUMERO 11802 del año 2016.- Lo expuesto consta en la escritura';
s.split(',').forEach(function(a){
  alert(a)
});
```

Comment: esta muy completa su respuesta estimado, pero en este momento no me encuentro programando, si no que mediante un software ingreso expresiones regulares que esta basado en C# and js

Comment: Entonces simplemente ingresa `[^,]+`, debería funcionar

Comment: si funciona esa expresion, pero solo toma la primera parte "Santa Elena.- FOJAS 8148 NUMERO 11796 del año 2016" pero estoy tratando de originar otra expresión o algo similar que busque la segunda parte de esa cadena.

Comment: te interesa únicamente la segunda "frase/parte"?

Comment: Podrias intentar agregando el modificador [/g](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) al final de la expresion regular para hacerla global, sino puede que sea una limitacion del software que estas usando

Comment: ya encontrado la forma de hacerlo, gracias !!!

Comment: ¿Como lo solucionaste?

Comment: por medio del mismo software, hice una configuración diferente pero aplicando la misma expresión regular. es casi similar a la función que has posteado.

Comment: Quizás podrías aceptar la respuesta entonces ;)

Comment: aceptada, se me fue hacerlo antes estimado jaja nuevo en la plataforma